# how to install Laravel in Windows 7 without composer?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to install Laravel-5 & connect with MySQL in Windows 7 without any composer or dependency manager, but I'm having troubles.

Does any one have any solution or any useful link?

Comment: Just use VirtualBox with Laravel Homestead

Comment: Why without composer? Just curious.

Comment: I just wanted to download laravel & start coding the application.

Comment: Don't really understand why you wouldn't use composer

Comment: It's not the way Laravel works.